# Восклицательный знак означает не равно

Tags: c

Восклицательный знак означает не равно. Вопрос у меня есть переменная `x=0`, и в цикле условие `!x`, потом заменяется на 1, так `!x` это `x!=0`(не равен 0) или `x!=1`(не равен 1)?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Восклицательный знак это операция отрицания, никакое «не равно» к нему отношения не имеет

Answer (score 4):

```
!x
```

рассматривается как применение "*не*" к *логическому* значению `x`.

При приведении целочисленного `x` к логическому значению 0 рассматривается как "ложь", ненулевое значение — как "истина".

Итак, если `x` равно 0, т.е. ложь, то значение `!x` является истинным. Истинное утверждение при этом — `x==0`.

Сравнение с 1 вообще некорректно, так как "не один" совсем не значит "ноль".

Таким образом, `!x` можно рассматривать как иную запись `x==0`.